# How to trigger a training job for new train data using app engine and deploy new model on Cloud ML?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml, google-app-engine-python

I am finding cloud composer to be hard, can someone help me with retraining a model using cloud ML and app engine and schedule it every week

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but here's some example code on how to retrain a model using cloud composer: https://github.com/rhaertel80/cloudai_samples/tree/master/ctr

Comment: Another example:  https://cloud.google.com/solutions/machine-learning/recommendation-system-tensorflow-deploy